# Java Servlet - need to use session tracking and generics

Tags: java, session, generics, servlets, parameters

I need to use session tracking in a servlet to keep track of all of the URLs of the pages that the user has used to link to servlet within the current browser session.  I also have to keep a counter of how many times each once has been used to reach the servlet. so lets say i have a servlet EndPage.

EndPage would have a table containing the URL and the number of visits for each URL.

anyone know the best way to go about this? If there is anything i was vague about let me know and i can clarify.

Comment: i thought i had.. this site is confusing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you want to use a ServletRequestListener: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequestListener.html

Using the `requestInitialized()` method, you can look at each request and get the URL.

To set the session timeout to 1 minute, add the following to web.xml:

```
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>1</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

Comment: ok ill try that. how much do you know about servlets?  i need to have this session only last a max of 60 seconds if it is inactive. then the session should become invalidated.  do i have to use cookies to do this? or is there another way?

Comment: also how exactly do i use this method, it wants a parameter of type ServletRequestEvent.  what would i put there?  wouldnt it be easier to use the session and get the attributes?

Comment: I used the HttpServletRequest method getHeader() with parameter "Referrer" to get the URL the visitor comes from. thanks though. if you could help me with these other questions that would be great.

Comment: Added session timeout info to the answer.